# Why do I have to reload the page for my JS event to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I created an on click nav bar for my homepage. I would like that the user clicks and then the nav bar opens. My code does work, however it only works one or two times and then it doesn't work the third time until I refresh the page.

Does anyone know why this is?

```js
var sliderMenu = document.getElementById("slider-menu");
var close = document.getElementById("X");


sliderMenu.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  activate();
  console.log(event)
});

close.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  closeNav();
});


function activate(event) {
  var sliderMenuOpen = document.getElementById("slider-menu-open");
  sliderMenuOpen.classList.toggle("width");
}

function closeNav(event) {
  var sliderMenuOpen = document.getElementById("slider-menu-open");
  sliderMenuOpen.classList.toggle("width-close");
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-menu" id="slider-menu">
  <p>More</p>
</div>
<div class="slider-menu-open" id="slider-menu-open">
  <a id="X" href="">X</a>
  <a href="">Carpet Cleaning</a>
  <a href="">Blinds</a>
  <a href="">Flooring</a>
  <a href="">Rugs</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please convert this to a snippet for us to examine? :)

Comment: I imagine that "width" and "width-close" should be the same class?

Comment: please add the css

Comment: You will have to elaborate on what "Doesnt Work" means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead. It removes the need for the extra class `width-close`

```
// i moved this to outside the functions so that you don't have to keep
// unnecessarily setting sliderMenuOpen
var sliderMenuOpen = document.getElementById("slider-menu-open");

var sliderMenu = document.getElementById("slider-menu");
var close = document.getElementById("X");
sliderMenu.addEventListener("click", (ev)=>{
    sliderMenuOpen.classList.add("width");
});
close.addEventListener("click", (ev)=>{
    sliderMenuOpen.classList.remove("width");
});
```

If you check the DOM with your old code you'll notice that they'll both be active (or inactive) at the wrong times after clicking close and open a few times.

Answer (score 0):

If you could share your CSS that would be helpful.

Whilst I'm not sure what your CSS is doing, the issue could be that you are toggling `width` when clicking `More` and `width-close` when clicking `X`.

On clicking `More` you add `width` class, then on clicking close you add `width-close` then when you click open again it REMOVES `width` (instead of adding it which is what it did the first time). then you click close and it adds  `width-close` again on its own.

this could be the cause, but without seeing the CSS I'm not sure.

It could be better if there was just one toggle function for both the close and the open which the X and the More would both use. You could then update the `More` text to say `Less` when the menu is open

Comment: apologies all I am trying to edit my code to add the css but it won't let me - here is a js fiddle instead: https://jsfiddle.net/angie11/d2xoLnc1/4/ It works once and then goes to a 404 error page in the fiddle, however on my actual website it works twice when I click it then stops. https://cb-carpet-cleaning-services.herokuapp.com/